# Can the mounted file system (NFS) be kept on another host if the VM is evacuated?

Tags: nfs, mount, high-availability, evaluation

I'd like to know about OpenStack High Availability.
If the node (VM) mounts the file system (NFS) (https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/latest/admin/nfs-backend.html) and the VM is evacuated in case of failure and moved to another host, can the mounted file system (NFS) be kept on another host?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your storage backend.

OpenStack volumes can have a setting `multiattach`. When set to `true` the same volume can be made available to two or more compute instances (VM's) concurrently.  https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/latest/admin/volume-multiattach.html

It is the responsibility of the compute instance to ensure data integrity for such volumes; a normal file system does not support two or more different nodes writing concurrently to the same block device. You will need a cluster file system  or a method to ensure that only one node at the same time will make changes to the block device.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!